# Is there support for 21 cm x 11 in paper?

Tags: paper-size

I have noticed that a few (online) academic journals use `21 cm x 11 in` (21 centimeters high, 11 inches wide) as their "paper" size. I suppose this serves to fit the manuscript on either letter or A4 paper without rescaling. Here is one example: https://ejnmmiphys.springeropen.com/articles

Is there a name for this kind of paper format so that I can easily use it without the `geometry` package, for instance?

Comment: Is `11 cm`, too?

Comment: @manooooh no, that's inches. I clarified the formatting of the question.

Comment: With geometry package, you can set any size you want (within TeX limits)

Comment: If a journal accepts submissions typed in TeX, then it has directions for authors on its website as to how submissions should be formatted, often with its own style file. Journals in most disciplines do not accept anything other than Microsoft Word documents. Check first with any journal that you might submit to.

Comment: I checked the first article at the link you gave https://ejnmmiphys.springeropen.com/track/pdf/10.1186/s40658-018-0239-2  and it does not have the page size you say, the document properties state:  a page size: `210 × 280 mm (portrait)`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh, good point. My (US English) Adobe Reader shows `8.27 x 11.02 in`, so I naturally assumed the latter one would be `11 in`, up to some rounding error. I has not crossed my mind that this could be some meaningful number in millimeters, too... So what page size is this then, anyway?

Comment: it's A4 without using the full length:-)

Comment: I would guess it's a compromise, for submissions that are either A4 (210 x 297mm) or US letter (8.5 x 11 in). If you scale down the US letter width to fit on A4 you get a height of 288mm. If you scale it down without reducing the margins somehow, you probably end up a bit less height, i.e. 280. An A4 page size looks unpleasantly "tall and narrow" anyway so the reduced height will improve that.

Comment: @alephzero "An A4 page size looks unpleasantly "tall and narrow" anyway" -- wooow, you want to start a culture war here? :)

Answer (score 4):

I am not seeing that journals actually require documents to be published in the 21cmx11in format.
Looking at the [submission guidelines for articles](https://ejnmmiphys.springeropen.com/submission-guidelines/preparing-your-manuscript/original-research-articles), it provides two preferred styles to download:

> BioMedCentral_article (ZIP format) - preferred template
>
> Springer article svjour3 (ZIP format) - preferred template

I downloaded the svjour3 one since the first one is specific to BioMed.
Looking at the svjour3.cls that comes with the zip, the relevant lines seem to be

```
\DeclareOption{a4paper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {297mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {210mm}}
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}}
\DeclareOption{twoside}{\@twosidetrue  \@mparswitchtrue}
\DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
\DeclareOption{final}{\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}}
```

Their fallback code is

```
\ExecuteOptions{a4paper,twoside,10pt,instindent}
```

As a side note, I have published with Springer (and with Online-only journals) and they, in my experience, prefer standard A4 format because even online-only journals want to generate .pdf files for download. Springer does list the standard TeX article class as a template download, too.

So not using the geometry package, one could set custom lengths and sizes using the built-in commands.

Answer (score 0):

The `memoir` class provides for some 33 paper sizes but not the one you state which is between A4 and letterpaper. The class does provide means of specifying your exact paper size. See the manual (`> texdoc memoir`) for how to do this.

Maybe, though, the journals will accept text on A4 that will print on letterpaper or text on letterpaper that will print on A4.